# RecyclerView like shopping apps

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make layout which has 2 post in a row(RecyclerView) and multiple rows like this. How can I do this.  What will be changes in my layout. 
I have adapter and a layout for a row and a layout where RecyclerView is placed.

Comment: Can you please show us some part of the code you refer to "this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` with 2 rows. 
Check this [link](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/) out, it shows how to make a recyclerView with 4 layouts in a row. so you can just tweak it for 2 layouts in a row

Comment: Thank a lot dude..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use GridView instead of RecyclerView?

Comment: No I have to use RecyclerView

Comment: I have already implemented RecyclerView

Comment: @Mayank so change it to GridView

Comment: That will be my last option.